# How get correct time zone offset on daylight saving in C#

Tags: c#, timezone, datetimeoffset

I am struggling to get a correct datetimeoffset when switching from winter to summer time.

What I am trying to do is to send a request to an API, and the parameters are two dates with following format:"`2018-03-01T01:00:00+01:00`"
I have created two Datetimeoffset in Paris TimeZone (my PC is in the UK but the API is a french service), here is how I did this:

```
var timeZoneInfo = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Romance Standard Time");
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2018,03,01,00,00,00);
dt = DateTime.SpecifyKind(dt, DateTimeKind.Local);
DateTimeOffset startingDate = new DateTimeOffset(dt);
startingDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(startingDate, timeZoneInfo);
DateTimeOffset endingDate = new DateTimeOffset();
for (int i = 0;i<700;i++)
{
     startingDate = startingDate.AddMonths(i);
     endingDate = startingDate.AddMonths(1);
     IRestResponse myquery= getAPIresult("", "", startingDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzzzz"), endingDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzzzzz"));
```

When executing the code, I get "`2018-03-01T01:00:00+01:00`" for startingDate, which is what I expect.

But I get "`2018-04-01T01:00:00+01:00`" for endingDate, which is strange as the 31st of March is the daylight saving in France, so the Paris timeZone such from GMT+01 to GMT+02.

So I should get "`2018-04-01T01:00:00+02:00`" for ending date.

If you could help me on this, I would really be thankfull.

Comment: The [`IsDaylightSavingTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.isdaylightsavingtime?view=netframework-4.8) method might be helpful here

Comment: I am not sure to understand your answer @IDarkCoder, [link]IsDateTimeOffset will just return a boolean, how can I use it?

Comment: well if its daylightsavings then its timezone +1 otherwise not (except for those places that half hour shift)

Comment: in 2018 the daylight saving time started on 25.03 and not on 01.04

Comment: When doing this: timeZoneInfo.IsDaylightSavingTime(endingDate), I get "true". Does that mean that I shoud change the timezone? (here change it to GTB Standard Time for instance). What is not clear to me is that I thought that by defining a timezone, the offset vs UTC time would adjust automatically to +2 on 25/03/2018

Comment: @mrspringer, yes indeed, but it does not change the fact that on 01/04/2018, the timezone offset should be +2 in Paris and not +1

Comment: @Nefarious62 "Romance Standard Time" is shared among several nations. Are you sure all those nations implement DST? If they don't, then it makes sense that .NET won't automatically apply DST adjustment.

Comment: @Zoomzoom - All valid time zone identifiers are self-consistent.  If the DST rules differed among the area they applied to, there would be different identifiers accordingly.  In the case of `"Romance Standard Time"`, the corresponding English display name is `"(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris"`, and applies to Belgium, Denmark, Spain, and France (mainlands of each, plus Ceuta).  All of these areas are EU countries in the CET/CEST time zone, with DST presently in effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime` within the loop, such that every value is re-evaluated against the time zone.  (The `DateTimeOffset` caries only the offset, not the time zone.)

Also, your logic of `.AddMonths(i)` is in error, as you are mutating the `startingDate` in the loop.  You can either use `.AddMonths(1)`, or you can hold the original starting date in a separate variable that doesn't mutate.

The simplest fix is thus:

```
startingDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(startingDate.AddMonths(1), timeZoneInfo);
endingDate = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(startingDate.AddMonths(1), timeZoneInfo);
```

Additionally, you might want to think about why you're introducing `DateTimeKind.Local` in the starting date at all.  It should be irrelevant for this task.  Consider perhaps instead:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2018, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0);
TimeSpan offset = timeZoneInfo.GetUtcOffset(dt);
DateTimeOffset startingDate = new DateTimeOffset(dt, offset);
```

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your help, this is more or less the solution I found. Thanks again